# Adding elements to a pre-defined array

Tags: matlab, octave

This is a snippet of code from a function I've created which given a word to find in a grid and the grid, finds the word in it. What I'm trying to do here is get the word in a given direction by moving from a starting point (which is what row and column are equal to). `rowdir` and `coldir` are dependent on a switch statement where if the direction is north-east for example, `rowdir=-1` and `coldir=1`. I want to output the word and then plot it on the grid.

```
word = zeros(1,len);
for index = 1:len
    index_1 = index-1;
    word(index) = grid1(row + (index_1 * rowdir), column + (index_1 * coldir));
end
```

I'm receiving this error and not sure how to solve it:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the
same.

Error in jifjffj (line 43)
        word(index) = grid1(row + (index_1 * rowdir), column + (index_1 *
        coldir));
```

If I enter the same code in the command prompt with row and column set to values such as 5 and rowdir and coldir adjusted for a particular direction and given a matrix, it has no problem in extracting the word in that direction for the length of letters specified so i'm unsure what the issue is here.

---

(EDIT from additional posted information):

I have also attempted the following which results in the same error message. I'm struggling to understand why.

```
testword= [];
for index = 1:len
    index_1 = index-1;
    word = grid(row + (index_1 * rowdir), column + (index_1 * coldir));
    testword(end+1) = word;
end
```

Comment: [row,column] = find(target(1)==grid);

where target is the word we are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `row` and `column` are not a single number. So your

```
grid1(row + (index_1 * rowdir), column + (index_1 * ...
        coldir))
```

is actually a 2D array while `word(len)` is only one single number.

Try this:

```
for index = 1:len
    index_1 = index-1;
    word = grid(row + (index_1 * rowdir), column + (index_1 * coldir));
    testword{index} = word;
end
```

Comment: Well they are in the format [row,column]. How would I be better off doing this?

Comment: try testword{index}=word;